# Destroy gameobject that is returning a RaycastHit2D?

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics

As the title suggests I would like to destroy the game object that my raycast hits.
I have a movement script attached to my player object. A raycast2d is continuously shot downward, and when it collides with an object on the enemy layer it registers the collision and returns its value. What I want to do now is destroy that object, however when I use the destroy game object command, it destroys the gameObject that the script is attached to, as one may expect. How can I destroy this enemy object, which the script is not attached to.

This is the current code that I am using:

```
bool HitEnemy()
{
    Vector2 position = transform.position;
    Vector2 direction = Vector2.down;
    float distance = 2.0f;
    
    
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position, direction, distance, enemyLayer);
    if (hit.collider != null) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false; 

    
}
```

I will be doing something similar, where my enemy shoots a horizontal ray, which will then kill the player character. How can I reference these 2?

I am relatively new to C# coding, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just updated the sentence I botched. Will add my code tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo that accomplishes what you are asking.

First, the set up -- the scene consists of a player sprite and 3 enemy sprites.

[image: set up]

The enemy sprites are assigned to the **Enemy** Layer. Each has a Collider2D component.

[image: Enemy -- Inspector]

The Player sprite is similar, but it also has a custom component attached and of course is not assigned to the Enemy layer.

[image: Player -- Inspector]

On to the script.
First we declare a couple of handy variables with sensible default values that we can adjust later in the  inspector:

```
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 m_RayDirection = Vector2.down;
    [SerializeField] private float m_RayRange = 4;
```

On **Start**, we let `LayerMask` do the bit-twiddling to calculate the correct mask value:

```
 int enemyLayer;
    void Start()
    {
       enemyLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("Enemy");
    }
```

The fun happens in Update. First, we'll move our player from side to side, simply for demo purposes. `Mathf.PingPong()` is a simple way to do this.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 4f) - 2.0f, 0, 0);
```

Now, we test for a hit using the parameters we've assembled:

```
   RaycastHit2D hit;
   hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, m_RayDirection, m_RayRange, enemyLayer);
        if (hit)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit " + hit.collider.name);
            //You could do other stuff here, like instantiate particles or play sounds...

            //Destroy the enemy GO:
            Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
        }
```

Here's the entire script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_X : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private Vector2 m_RayDirection = Vector2.down;
    [SerializeField] private float m_RayRange = 4;

    int enemyLayer;
    void Start()
    {
       enemyLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("Enemy");
    }

    RaycastHit2D hit;
    void Update()
    {
        //Move the Player back and forth across the screen, for demo
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 4f) - 2.0f, 0, 0);

        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, m_RayDirection, m_RayRange, enemyLayer);
        if (hit)
        {
            //Draw a debug ray to see what's happening
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, m_RayDirection * m_RayRange, Color.green,.5f);

            Debug.Log("Hit " + hit.collider.name);
            //You could do other stuff here, like instantiate particles or play sounds...

            //Destroy the enemy GO:
            Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have been so stuck on this, and your reply is so well formatted and informative.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found it helpful.

Comment: One final question,  when attempting to use Debug.DrawRay and assign a color I get the error that 'color does not exist in the current context'. Any possible insight?

Comment: 1) what makes you say the ray is casting too far? Can you share your set-up? 2) can you share the relevant code that is drawing the debug ray?

Comment: The Ray Range being set at 4 made contact with the enemy sprite, before the player sprite was close enough. I just edited it in inspector, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward, Color.green);

I just copied this from the Unity Documentation, so I'm sure there is some sort of concept I am missing in the functionality of the DrawRay method.

Comment: I added code to the script above to illustrate how to add the Debug ray. I think your problem was the second argument, which should be a direction vector. Note I am passing 4 arguments, the last one is how long the ray stays visible...

Comment: You are seriously the best, thank you again. 
Do you have any of your games online anywhere? I'd love to check them out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try something like this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out hit)
{
    Destroy(hit.gameobject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try ASAP.

Comment: `Physics.Raycast()` works in 3D, its 2D counterpart is [`Physics2D.Raycast()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)